# Argument `needs_dots` in R (tibble)

Tags: r, warnings, pandoc, tibble

Since a while ago tibble is throwing warning messages (although the outputs are correct). The only thing I remember changing before it had started was re-installing pandoc. If I keep data in data.frame, there is no such warning. This is how the message looks like. How do I fix it?

```
df <- data.frame('A' = c(1, 2), 'B' = c('a', 'b'))
df
```

```
> df
  A B
1 1 a
2 2 b
```

```
tibble::as_tibble(df)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      A B    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b 

Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

'We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`'

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
```

Comment: This is a known "bug" since R changed some of its internal handling dots and was discussed on the R-devel mailing list a few weeks ago. AFAIK it was filed as a bug to the tibble developers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Julian_Hn, after an update to 3.0.3 version, the warning does not appear anymore.